# Get a true / false column if last 2 days were red in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of symbols in a single df:

```
         index        date symbol  stock_id  open  high     low  close    volume      vwap
0            0  2021-10-11    BVN        13  7.69  7.98  7.5600   7.61    879710  7.782174
1            1  2021-10-12    BVN        13  7.67  8.08  7.5803   8.02    794436  7.967061
2            2  2021-10-13    BVN        13  8.12  8.36  8.0900   8.16    716012  8.231286
3            3  2021-10-14    BVN        13  8.26  8.29  8.0500   8.28    586091  8.185899
4            4  2021-10-15    BVN        13  8.18  8.44  8.0600   8.44   1278409  8.284539
...        ...         ...    ...       ...   ...   ...     ...    ...       ...       ...
227774  227774  2022-10-04   ERIC     11000  6.27  6.32  6.2400   6.29  14655189  6.280157
227775  227775  2022-10-05   ERIC     11000  6.17  6.31  6.1500   6.29  10569193  6.219965
227776  227776  2022-10-06   ERIC     11000  6.20  6.25  6.1800   6.22   7918812  6.217198
227777  227777  2022-10-07   ERIC     11000  6.17  6.19  6.0800   6.10   9671252  6.135976
227778  227778  2022-10-10   ERIC     11000  6.13  6.15  6.0200   6.04   6310661  6.066256

[227779 rows x 10 columns]
```

I want to be able to get each unique stock and return a new column of true / false depending on if the last two days were red, e.g:

```
         index        date symbol  stock_id  open  high     low  close    volume      vwap  is_downtrending
0            0  2021-10-11    BVN        13  7.69  7.98  7.5600   7.61    879710  7.782174  False
1            1  2021-10-12    BVN        13  7.67  8.08  7.5803   8.02    794436  7.967061  False
2            2  2021-10-13    BVN        13  8.12  8.36  8.0900   8.16    716012  8.231286  False
3            3  2021-10-14    BVN        13  8.26  8.29  8.0500   8.28    586091  8.185899  True
4            4  2021-10-15    BVN        13  8.18  8.44  8.0600   8.44   1278409  8.284539  True
...        ...         ...    ...       ...   ...   ...     ...    ...       ...       ...
227774  227774  2022-10-04   ERIC     11000  6.27  6.32  6.2400   6.29  14655189  6.280157  True
227775  227775  2022-10-05   ERIC     11000  6.17  6.31  6.1500   6.29  10569193  6.219965  True
227776  227776  2022-10-06   ERIC     11000  6.20  6.25  6.1800   6.22   7918812  6.217198  True
227777  227777  2022-10-07   ERIC     11000  6.17  6.19  6.0800   6.10   9671252  6.135976  False
227778  227778  2022-10-10   ERIC     11000  6.13  6.15  6.0200   6.04   6310661  6.066256  True

[227779 rows x 10 columns]
```

Something like:

```
ticker_group=df.groupby(['stock_id'])

final_df = pd.DataFrame()


def is_downtrending(close):
    out = np.full(close.shape, False)

    for i in range(close.shape[0]):
        # if we've had two consecutive red days
        if (close[i] < close[i - 1]) and (close[i - 1] < close[i - 2]):
            out[i] = True
        else:
            out[i] = False

    return out

for index, ohlc in ticker_group:

    ohlc['is_downtrending'] = is_downtrending(ohlc['close'])

    final_df = ohlc
```

How do I return a new column of true / false values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a `groupby`+`rolling`:

```
N = 2
df['is_downtrending'] = (df.groupby('symbol')['close']
                           .apply(lambda s: s.diff().lt(0).rolling(N).sum().eq(N))
                          )
```

Output:

```
         index        date symbol  stock_id  open  high     low  close    volume      vwap  is_downtrending
0            0  2021-10-11    BVN        13  7.69  7.98  7.5600   7.61    879710  7.782174            False
1            1  2021-10-12    BVN        13  7.67  8.08  7.5803   8.02    794436  7.967061            False
2            2  2021-10-13    BVN        13  8.12  8.36  8.0900   8.16    716012  8.231286            False
3            3  2021-10-14    BVN        13  8.26  8.29  8.0500   8.28    586091  8.185899            False
4            4  2021-10-15    BVN        13  8.18  8.44  8.0600   8.44   1278409  8.284539            False
227774  227774  2022-10-04   ERIC     11000  6.27  6.32  6.2400   6.29  14655189  6.280157            False
227776  227776  2022-10-06   ERIC     11000  6.20  6.25  6.1800   6.22   7918812  6.217198            False
227777  227777  2022-10-07   ERIC     11000  6.17  6.19  6.0800   6.10   9671252  6.135976             True
227778  227778  2022-10-10   ERIC     11000  6.13  6.15  6.0200   6.04   6310661  6.066256             True
```

Comment: you're a legend mate, thank you